Go Gin Framework cors error for gin router group
I am building a full-stack project using Golang and Angular 18. I’ve encountered a CORS issue. When I try to access http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login (POST) from the frontend, there is no CORS error. However, when I try to access http://localhost:8080/api/v1/todos (GET), I encounter a CORS error (for /todos/*) . Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?
Here’s the error when I try to access http://localhost:8080/api/v1/todos (GET):
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/todos' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
This is my main.go.
package main

import (
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/auth"
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/database"
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/todo"
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/user"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    database.LoadConfig()
    database.ConnectDB()
    log.Println("Database Connected Successfully")

    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Use(gin.Logger())
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())

    apiGroup := router.Group("/api/v1")
    
    userApi := user.NewUserController()
    todoApi := todo.NewTodoController()
    authApi := auth.NewAuthController()

    userApi.Router(apiGroup)
    authApi.Router(apiGroup)
    todoApi.Router(apiGroup)

    port := viper.GetString("port")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }

    if err := router.Run(":" + port); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

This is my todo pkg.
package todo

import (
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/middleware"
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/repository"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type TodoHandler struct {
    TodoStore repository.TodoRepos
    UserStore repository.UserRepos
}

func NewTodoController() TodoHandler {
    t := repository.NewTodoRepos()
    u := repository.NewUserRepos()
    return TodoHandler{
        TodoStore: t,
        UserStore: u,
    }
}

func (t *TodoHandler) Router(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    todo := router.Group("/todos")
    todo.Use(middleware.AuthMiddleware())
    todo.POST("/", t.CreateTodo)
    todo.GET("/", t.ListTodo)
    todo.GET("/:id", t.GetTodo)
    todo.PUT("/:id", t.UpdateTodo)
    todo.DELETE("/:id", t.DeleteTodo)
}

This is my auth pkg.
package auth

import (
    "github.com/JahidNishat/DailyPractice/todo-app/todo-backend/internal/repository"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type AuthHandler struct {
    UserStore repository.UserRepos
}

func NewAuthController() AuthHandler {
    u := repository.NewUserRepos()
    return AuthHandler{
        UserStore: u,
    }
}

func (a *AuthHandler) Router(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    auth := router.Group("/auth")
    auth.POST("/login", a.LogIn)
    auth.POST("/register", a.Register)
}

I tried github.com/gin-contrib/cors pkg. Use router.Use(cors.Default()). Also used:
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

router.Use(CORSMiddleware())

But it does'not solve the cors error.

difference is probably a simple request vs. fetch or JS request.   For the CORS error, you might try explicitly allowing "localhost:4200", as wildcarding origins with credentials is not allowed. (may also need to be https)  I usually just create a profile for local debugging with --disable-web-security flag.  That's so I don't forget to remove CORS headers when going live as those will decrease your security.  (keep everything same-site/domain)

the order of your CORS middleware is sometimes important... usually after routing and before authentication.  (but I'm not familiar with Gin so hopefully someone with Gin experience will chime in)

Please [edit] and provide a proper [mre] that we can run to reproduce your issue. This includes: The code that makes the problematic request for which you get the CORS error, the code that's supposed to run for this particular request, the code for any particular middleware that run for this request (You can skip third party one's as long as you show their usage and mention which package they are from).

Do you use a proxy configuration for your angular app?
For example:
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ['/api-shift'],
    target: "http://localhost:9098/shift-service",
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    // pathRewrite: {'^/api-shift': ''},
    logLevel: 'debug',
  },
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

I get this same error when I work my angular app but this file solve this problem for me.

When developing backend with Gin on the localhost, I used this method.
func (app *application) CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", app.config.allowOrigin)
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

func (app *application) initRouters() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(app.CORSMiddleware())
    r.POST("/upload/files", YOUR_HANDLER)
    // custom routes ....
    r.SetTrustedProxies(nil)
}

Also try using this chrome extension.
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf
Hope it will help you. 

origin never needs to be listed in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header; see https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header. Also, c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" is too restrictive; see https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly. I recommend relying on a CORS middleware library (and a good one, if possible) rather than implementing CORS "by hand".
